# Programatically running Python programs in virtual environments (conda or venv)

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, conda, python-venv

I am planning to implement some functionality in Python to be used as part of a larger non-Python project, so as to take advantage of some Python libraries. I have done some scripting in Python before, but nothing this substantial.

From the advice I've gotten, it seems like we will definitely want to use a virtual environment to manage dependencies. I am exploring venv and conda and haven't committed to either yet, though it seems like conda would have the advantage of providing pre-built versions of Cython dependencies.

With both conda and venv, though, the documentation I've been finding seems to be oriented toward working interactively inside the environment. For our purposes, I want to be able to run the programs we've written in Python programmatically, without going through the system shell.

Is there an established, recommended way to do this?

I've been trying to look at what the Bash scripts to activate a virtual environment actually do, and it looks like they basically just set up some environment variables. Both add their virtual environment's `bin` directory to the beginning of the `PATH`, venv sets `VIRTUAL_ENV`, and conda sets a bunch of `CONDA_` environment variables. Interestingly, it doesn't look like either sets, say, `PYTHONPATH`.

For programmatic use, is it sufficient to set these environment variables and then run the equivalent of `python3 -m mymodule`, or is there more setup that needs to be done? I would particularly like to know if this is documented anywhere, for conda, venv, or both: relying on having figured out what environment variables need to be set to what values seems a bit fragile.

Comment: I've done something similar before, and I've found [this](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/) very helpful. I ended up using bash scripts to enter the virtual env using `source my_project_name/bin/activate`, running all the Python code in the venv, then using `deactivate` to leave the venv.

Comment: for virtualenv I think the only thing necessary is running the python at `<venv>/bin/python`. Setting the environment variables is just a convenient way of making sure that happens.

Comment: ( or if that is not possible because another python interpreter is already running you can use [these instructions](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/userguide/#using-virtualenv-without-bin-python))